# need excel formula for multiple row column lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need formula to populate Date of admission in Sheet 1, considering the data from Sheet 2

Sheet 1:

```
Column: Patient number || Date of Admission
Data 1: 1234           ||
Data 2: 9876           ||
Data 3: 4357           ||
```

Sheet 2:

```
Column: Patient Number || 01/08/2018 || 02/08/2018 || 03/08/2018 || 04/08/2018
Data 1: 1234           ||Admission   ||at hospital ||at hospital ||at hospital
Data 2: 9876           ||            ||Admission   ||at hospital ||discharge 
Data 3: 4357           ||            ||            ||            ||Admission
```

I need a formula that populates the admission date in 'Date of Admission' column in Sheet 1, based on the day in which admissions have taken place.

So the formula should generate below result in sheet 1:

```
Column: Patient number || Date of Admission
Data 1: 1234           ||01/08/2018
Data 2: 9876           ||02/08/2018
Data 3: 4357           ||04/08/2018
```

I have tried using all possible options. I reached very closely using **Index and Match formula,** but I am not able to generate the corresponding date in Sheet 2.

Any help or suggestion will be very very helpful.

Comment: are the patient numbers unique in the first column and is there only one `Admission` per row?

Comment: yes the patients number are unique and yes there is only 1 admission per row.

Answer (score 0):

If your you only have one `Admission` per row you can use this:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(F:I,MATCH(A2,E:E,0),0),"A",$F$1:$I$1)
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$I$1,MATCH("A",INDEX(F:I,MATCH(A2,E:E,0),0),0))
```

You will need to format the result as a short date.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott.. Loved it.. it worked.. your response was bang on target and so quick..
Can you also tell me what changes i need to do if **there are two or more Admission per row**

Comment: That depends on how you want the output to be displayed, do you want the first, the second, the last?

Comment: Yes. The first admission comes in column 'Date of Admission' and second comes in another column 'Date of Re-admission'

Answer (score 0):

**ONLY WORKS IF THE TWO PATIENTS LISTS ARE IN THE SAME ORDER**

```
Data 1: 1234    =INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$F$1,MATCH("admission",Sheet2!C2:F2,0))

Data 2: 9876    =INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$F$1,MATCH("admission",Sheet2!C3:F3,0))

Data 3: 4357    =INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$F$1,MATCH("admission",Sheet2!C4:F4,0))
```

Put `=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$F$1,MATCH("admission",Sheet2!C2:F2,0))` into cell C2 and copy it down and you should be covered. Make sure you change the ranges to encompass all of your data, let me know if you have any questions ;) **Make sure your answer is formatted as short date (change the format of the formula cells to short date)**

Comment: Just an FYI to the OP:  This works only if the two list of patient numbers are exact and in the same order.  If that is the case then this is the better answer.

Comment: Thank you Blake. This solution does work too. Awesome thanks for the support.

Comment: Hello Scott / Blake,
I need further help. 
On the above data, what if Admission "A" is in a different sheet and not in the same sheet.
I basically make this sheet on monthly basis, but the patient can be admitted in previous month.
So i want to scan the sheet of all the months to identify when the patient was admitted.
Will any formula work or I would need to use VBA ?